# Use derived keying material as key for stream cipher

Tags: key-derivation, pseudo-random-function

Section 7.3 of [SP 800-108](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-108/final):

> To comply with this Recommendation, the derived keying material **shall not** be used as a key stream for a stream cipher.

Footnote:

> The level of security provided by using the key derivation functions specified in this Recommendation to generate a key stream for stream ciphers has not been investigated.

I was wondering why the derived keying material can be cut into valid cryptographic keys but cannot be used for stream cipher. Since it is marked as a **shall not**, are there any serious concerns if the derived keying material is used for stream cipher (other than it may not be long enough for given plaintext)?